# How to mask certain values in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some values on a certain map. But I do not want to plot the 0-values. How could I do this?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
)
ax.set_extent([10, 20, 10, 20], crs=proj)

# reading data
ds  = xr.open_dataset(fname)
tqc = ds.tqc[0,:] 

# get lon and lat values
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)

# creating plot
plt.tricontourf(clon, clat, tqc, cmap='magma_r')
colorbar_tqi = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3.2), cmap='magma_r'),
             ax=ax, orientation='vertical', label='TQI [kg/m2]', pad = 0.01, shrink=.53)
```

And in the same way I was wondering how I could set the colorbar height exactly to the height of my figure. Here, I used shrink, where I tried some values to see which one fits the best, but that does not seem a correct way of doing it.

###### EDIT

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# data
ds  = xr.open_dataset(fname)
tqc = ds.tqc[0,:]

# lon und lat to degrees
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)

# create boolean
keep_bool = tqc.values > 0.05

clon = clon[keep_bool]
clat = clat[keep_bool]
tqc_masked = tqc[keep_bool]

# plot
mappable = ax.tricontourf(clon, clat, tqc_masked, cmap='plasma', vmin=0.5, vmax=3.2)
fig.colorbar(mappable, pad=0.01, label='TQC [kg/m$^2$]')
```

But here I have the following problem: First, vmin and vmax do not work and second, the mask gives me a "ValueError: z array must have same length as triangulation x and y arrays". I have checked and as well as tqc, clon and clat have the same shape before and after masking.

###### EDIT 2

Let's phrase it in other words: I want to reproduce the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# data
ds  = xr.open_dataset(fname)
tqc = ds.tqc[0,:]

# lon und lat to degrees
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)

# plot
boundaries = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8]
colors = ('#c4c4e4','#8989c9','#4e4eaf','#141494','#272776','#626256','#9d9d35','#d8d815') #,'#f6eb00','#dbb100','#c17600','#a63b00','#8b0000')
mappable = ax.tricontourf(clon, clat, tqc, colors=colors, levels=boundaries)
fig.colorbar(mappable, pad=0.01, label='TQC [kg/m$^2$]')
```

with the following outcome:

[image: TQC plottet with boundaries explicitly set]
but without setting the boundaries and the colors explicitly. I just want to mask all values smaller than 0.2 and draw the other values in a certain cmap. But if I use masking

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# data
ds  = xr.open_dataset(fname)
tqc = ds.tqc[0,:]

# lon und lat to degrees
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)

# create boolean
keep_bool = tqc.values > 0.2

clon = clon[keep_bool]
clat = clat[keep_bool]
tqc_masked = tqc.values[keep_bool]

# plot
mappable = ax.tricontourf(clon, clat, tqc_masked, cmap='plasma')
fig.colorbar(mappable, pad=0.01, label='TQC [kg/m$^2$]')
```

it does not mask the values < 0.2.

[image: same output but with masking]

###### EDIT 3

It still does not work for me :( I do not really know why, but it looks weird with different mask_below values. I use the following code:

```
# data
ds  = xr.open_dataset(fname)
tqc = ds.tqc[0,:]

# lon und lat to degrees
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)

# create boolean
mask_below = 0.2

#Define a colormap where values <= vmin are white
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
cmap.set_under('white')

#Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

mappable = ax.tricontourf(clon, clat, tqc, cmap=cmap, vmin=mask_below)
cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, label='TQI (kg/m$^2$)')

#Adjust the colour bar limits to remove the masked values
mask_above = cbar.ax.get_ylim()[1]
cbar.ax.set_ylim(mask_below, mask_above)

#Extra formatting: labels and spines
ax.set(xlabel='clon', ylabel='clat')
ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
```

If I set mask_below=0.2, it does not mask the values below 0.2:

[image: masking_error]

And if I use a different value, like mask_below=0.35, it masks values, but it does not adjust the colorbar:

[image: colorbar_error]

###### xarray.DataArray

```
ncells_dim=100
clon=np.array([0.5111043 , 0.5123288 , 0.51195335, 0.512205  , 0.51355225,
       0.51477456, 0.51440084, 0.5146535 , 0.5142793 , 0.5130547 ,
       0.5134298 , 0.51317763, 0.51330703, 0.51453215, 0.5141575 ,
       0.51441056, 0.5140354 , 0.512808  , 0.5131841 , 0.5129315 ,
       0.5115795 , 0.51035   , 0.5107277 , 0.51047623, 0.5108535 ,
       0.51208085, 0.51170444, 0.51195645, 0.511829  , 0.51060224,
       0.51097906, 0.510728  , 0.5091193 , 0.5078875 , 0.50826705,
       0.5080166 , 0.5066546 , 0.5054207 , 0.5058019 , 0.5055526 ,
       0.50593334, 0.507165  , 0.50678515, 0.507035  , 0.5069154 ,
       0.5056842 , 0.5060645 , 0.5058155 , 0.5061953 , 0.5074242 ,
       0.50704527, 0.5072948 , 0.508652  , 0.5098787 , 0.5095015 ,
       0.50975204, 0.5093744 , 0.50814545, 0.50852394, 0.50827396,
       0.5083956 , 0.50962514, 0.509247  , 0.50949794, 0.5096283 ,
       0.50840217, 0.5087797 , 0.5085301 , 0.5071749 , 0.5059466 ,
       0.50632584, 0.5060773 , 0.5064561 , 0.5076822 , 0.5073042 ,
       0.50755334, 0.50743324, 0.5062077 , 0.506586  , 0.5063378 ,
       0.5056702 , 0.50690466, 0.5065238 , 0.50677407, 0.5081381 ,
       0.5093704 , 0.5089913 , 0.5092426 , 0.508863  , 0.5076284 ,
       0.5080089 , 0.5077581 , 0.5078794 , 0.5091145 , 0.5087344 ,
       0.5089861 , 0.51060164, 0.51183176, 0.51145434, 0.51170677],
      dtype=np.float32)
clat=np.array([1.1715792, 1.1713854, 1.1716133, 1.1718533, 1.1711911, 1.1709963,
       1.1712245, 1.1714643, 1.1716925, 1.1718872, 1.171659 , 1.1714191,
       1.1721269, 1.1719323, 1.1721605, 1.1724002, 1.1726284, 1.172823 ,
       1.1725948, 1.172355 , 1.173017 , 1.1732106, 1.1729827, 1.1727428,
       1.1725149, 1.1723211, 1.1725491, 1.172789 , 1.1720812, 1.172275 ,
       1.172047 , 1.1718072, 1.1734039, 1.1735966, 1.1733688, 1.1731288,
       1.1737889, 1.1739807, 1.1737531, 1.1735132, 1.1732855, 1.1730936,
       1.1733212, 1.1735612, 1.1728535, 1.1730455, 1.1728178, 1.1725779,
       1.1723502, 1.1721581, 1.1723858, 1.1726258, 1.1719656, 1.1717726,
       1.1720005, 1.1722404, 1.1724683, 1.1726612, 1.1724334, 1.1721934,
       1.172901 , 1.1727082, 1.1729361, 1.1731759, 1.1715326, 1.1717256,
       1.1714978, 1.1712577, 1.171918 , 1.1721101, 1.1718825, 1.1716424,
       1.1714147, 1.1712226, 1.1714503, 1.1716903, 1.1709825, 1.1711746,
       1.170947 , 1.1707069, 1.1742207, 1.1740289, 1.1742566, 1.1744964,
       1.1738365, 1.1736437, 1.1738715, 1.1741114, 1.1743393, 1.1745319,
       1.1743041, 1.1740643, 1.1747718, 1.1745791, 1.174807 , 1.1750468,
       1.1734505, 1.1732569, 1.1734848, 1.1737247], dtype=np.float32)
tqc_values=np.array([0.15569663, 0.11916991, 0.11858897, 0.10107199, 0.15579152,
       0.13194141, 0.14021584, 0.11554057, 0.0784738 , 0.07480974,
       0.09887432, 0.12334369, 0.0665338 , 0.0794786 , 0.06426689,
       0.05735027, 0.09237053, 0.11770064, 0.12878077, 0.11895558,
       0.13666902, 0.16525495, 0.13639313, 0.128966  , 0.12359453,
       0.12086542, 0.14622061, 0.13807052, 0.09360459, 0.13403493,
       0.11391085, 0.12349615, 0.11537005, 0.12506713, 0.08103316,
       0.08701873, 0.15411958, 0.17143962, 0.14882892, 0.10075304,
       0.05091187, 0.07667481, 0.06803349, 0.12026618, 0.09903781,
       0.04676978, 0.08345287, 0.11008713, 0.12116196, 0.10179084,
       0.10546485, 0.09939726, 0.11531032, 0.14638193, 0.12827232,
       0.12819426, 0.0956176 , 0.11703059, 0.08874848, 0.09444176,
       0.1384329 , 0.11361963, 0.12464031, 0.14904864, 0.1392543 ,
       0.11825788, 0.11579482, 0.09708434, 0.13313244, 0.1233273 ,
       0.1366036 , 0.13449918, 0.11231212, 0.08745293, 0.10871083,
       0.11593907, 0.08150337, 0.10770909, 0.1069753 , 0.10310051,
       0.15952688, 0.17038634, 0.15969357, 0.10159207, 0.13086197,
       0.09630024, 0.12349406, 0.09031961, 0.11969905, 0.07538784,
       0.12515202, 0.16452919, 0.07986163, 0.1322178 , 0.12553921,
       0.12195621, 0.16712797, 0.1502901 , 0.1711053 , 0.14726645],
      dtype=np.float32)
time=np.datetime64('2024-02-02T21:00:00.000000000')

# Create the DataArray with coordinates and attributes
tqc_dataarray = xr.DataArray(
    data=tqc_values,
    dims=["ncells",],
    coords=dict(
        time=time,
        clon=('ncells', clon),
        clat=('ncells', clat)
    ),
    attrs=dict(
        standard_name='tqc',
        long_name='total column integrated cloud water',
        units='kg m-2'
    ),
    name='tqc'
)
```

Comment: For the first question, did you consider to filter out the 0 values before plotting them? Something like this: `non_zero_values = values.where(values != 0, drop=True)`

Comment: For the colorbar next map projections, see e.g. [Correct placement of colorbar relative to geo axes (cartopy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030328/correct-placement-of-colorbar-relative-to-geo-axes-cartopy).

Comment: yes, I can't drop them as then some arrays don't have the same length anymore

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, values below `mask_below` are coloured in white, making them appear masked. It's achieved by using `.set_under("white")` and `vmin=` to map values to the colour white. The ticks and limits of the colour bar are adjusted to hide the white parts of the scale.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

clon=np.array([0.5111043 , 0.5123288 , 0.51195335, 0.512205  , 0.51355225,
       0.51477456, 0.51440084, 0.5146535 , 0.5142793 , 0.5130547 ,
       0.5134298 , 0.51317763, 0.51330703, 0.51453215, 0.5141575 ,
       0.51441056, 0.5140354 , 0.512808  , 0.5131841 , 0.5129315 ,
       0.5115795 , 0.51035   , 0.5107277 , 0.51047623, 0.5108535 ,
       0.51208085, 0.51170444, 0.51195645, 0.511829  , 0.51060224,
       0.51097906, 0.510728  , 0.5091193 , 0.5078875 , 0.50826705,
       0.5080166 , 0.5066546 , 0.5054207 , 0.5058019 , 0.5055526 ,
       0.50593334, 0.507165  , 0.50678515, 0.507035  , 0.5069154 ,
       0.5056842 , 0.5060645 , 0.5058155 , 0.5061953 , 0.5074242 ,
       0.50704527, 0.5072948 , 0.508652  , 0.5098787 , 0.5095015 ,
       0.50975204, 0.5093744 , 0.50814545, 0.50852394, 0.50827396,
       0.5083956 , 0.50962514, 0.509247  , 0.50949794, 0.5096283 ,
       0.50840217, 0.5087797 , 0.5085301 , 0.5071749 , 0.5059466 ,
       0.50632584, 0.5060773 , 0.5064561 , 0.5076822 , 0.5073042 ,
       0.50755334, 0.50743324, 0.5062077 , 0.506586  , 0.5063378 ,
       0.5056702 , 0.50690466, 0.5065238 , 0.50677407, 0.5081381 ,
       0.5093704 , 0.5089913 , 0.5092426 , 0.508863  , 0.5076284 ,
       0.5080089 , 0.5077581 , 0.5078794 , 0.5091145 , 0.5087344 ,
       0.5089861 , 0.51060164, 0.51183176, 0.51145434, 0.51170677],
      dtype=np.float32)
clat=np.array([1.1715792, 1.1713854, 1.1716133, 1.1718533, 1.1711911, 1.1709963,
       1.1712245, 1.1714643, 1.1716925, 1.1718872, 1.171659 , 1.1714191,
       1.1721269, 1.1719323, 1.1721605, 1.1724002, 1.1726284, 1.172823 ,
       1.1725948, 1.172355 , 1.173017 , 1.1732106, 1.1729827, 1.1727428,
       1.1725149, 1.1723211, 1.1725491, 1.172789 , 1.1720812, 1.172275 ,
       1.172047 , 1.1718072, 1.1734039, 1.1735966, 1.1733688, 1.1731288,
       1.1737889, 1.1739807, 1.1737531, 1.1735132, 1.1732855, 1.1730936,
       1.1733212, 1.1735612, 1.1728535, 1.1730455, 1.1728178, 1.1725779,
       1.1723502, 1.1721581, 1.1723858, 1.1726258, 1.1719656, 1.1717726,
       1.1720005, 1.1722404, 1.1724683, 1.1726612, 1.1724334, 1.1721934,
       1.172901 , 1.1727082, 1.1729361, 1.1731759, 1.1715326, 1.1717256,
       1.1714978, 1.1712577, 1.171918 , 1.1721101, 1.1718825, 1.1716424,
       1.1714147, 1.1712226, 1.1714503, 1.1716903, 1.1709825, 1.1711746,
       1.170947 , 1.1707069, 1.1742207, 1.1740289, 1.1742566, 1.1744964,
       1.1738365, 1.1736437, 1.1738715, 1.1741114, 1.1743393, 1.1745319,
       1.1743041, 1.1740643, 1.1747718, 1.1745791, 1.174807 , 1.1750468,
       1.1734505, 1.1732569, 1.1734848, 1.1737247], dtype=np.float32)
tqc_values=np.array([0.15569663, 0.11916991, 0.11858897, 0.10107199, 0.15579152,
       0.13194141, 0.14021584, 0.11554057, 0.0784738 , 0.07480974,
       0.09887432, 0.12334369, 0.0665338 , 0.0794786 , 0.06426689,
       0.05735027, 0.09237053, 0.11770064, 0.12878077, 0.11895558,
       0.13666902, 0.16525495, 0.13639313, 0.128966  , 0.12359453,
       0.12086542, 0.14622061, 0.13807052, 0.09360459, 0.13403493,
       0.11391085, 0.12349615, 0.11537005, 0.12506713, 0.08103316,
       0.08701873, 0.15411958, 0.17143962, 0.14882892, 0.10075304,
       0.05091187, 0.07667481, 0.06803349, 0.12026618, 0.09903781,
       0.04676978, 0.08345287, 0.11008713, 0.12116196, 0.10179084,
       0.10546485, 0.09939726, 0.11531032, 0.14638193, 0.12827232,
       0.12819426, 0.0956176 , 0.11703059, 0.08874848, 0.09444176,
       0.1384329 , 0.11361963, 0.12464031, 0.14904864, 0.1392543 ,
       0.11825788, 0.11579482, 0.09708434, 0.13313244, 0.1233273 ,
       0.1366036 , 0.13449918, 0.11231212, 0.08745293, 0.10871083,
       0.11593907, 0.08150337, 0.10770909, 0.1069753 , 0.10310051,
       0.15952688, 0.17038634, 0.15969357, 0.10159207, 0.13086197,
       0.09630024, 0.12349406, 0.09031961, 0.11969905, 0.07538784,
       0.12515202, 0.16452919, 0.07986163, 0.1322178 , 0.12553921,
       0.12195621, 0.16712797, 0.1502901 , 0.1711053 , 0.14726645],
      dtype=np.float32)

ds = pd.DataFrame({'clon': clon, 'clat': clat, 't': tqc_values})

# Lat and long to degrees
clon = np.rad2deg(ds.clon.values)
clat = np.rad2deg(ds.clat.values)
mask_below = 0.10

#Define a colormap where values <= vmin are white
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
cmap.set_under('white')

#Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.scatter(clon, clat, marker='^', s=15, c='black', zorder=2)
mappable = ax.tricontourf(clon, clat, ds.t.values, cmap=cmap, vmin=mask_below)
cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, label='TQI (kg/m$^2$)')

#Adjust the colour bar limits to remove the masked values
from matplotlib import ticker
prev_levels = mappable.levels
new_levels = prev_levels[prev_levels > mask_below]
new_levels = np.insert(new_levels, 0, mask_below)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(new_levels))
cbar.ax.set_ylim(mask_below, mappable.levels[-1])

#Extra formatting: labels and spines
ax.set(xlabel='clon', ylabel='clat')
ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: The masking gives me a ValueEreror and the vmin and vmax parameters do not work for me. See my Edit above.

Comment: It looks `tqc_masked` is created, but `tqc` is being plotted. If you replace it with `tqc_masked` does it resolve the error?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up my two cells. No, it does not solve it. Thats where the ValueError occurs. I edited up in the code.

Comment: To ensure indexing is consistent, try `tqc_masked = tqc.values[keep_bool]`.

Comment: I have changed that, but it does not do what I want. I edited my post again to show you what I mean.

Comment: Still does not work as I'd like it to work :(

Comment: Please provide some sample data that replicates the problem if possible. One way is to run `ds.to_clipboard()` and paste some or all of the output into pastebin.com or into your question.

Comment: I copied a subset of the whole tqc xarray dataarray to the question above.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the supplied data.

Comment: Thanks. But I'll give up. Still does not work...

Comment: Okay, no problem. The sticking point seems to be when we switch from the sample dataset to the complete dataset.